# how to remove mistake:Permission is only granted to system apps in the Manifest

Tags: android

i develop a app using

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
```

i know it is a system Permission,i want to do finish my app,and then put my app as system apps. but when i compile my app,it is give the mistake at android manifest:Permission is only granted to system apps,so my app always not run. how to can finish it. i want to first finish my app,and then put it as system app.So, can anyone give me some tips on how to do this?

Comment: I am also getting same message.below answer didnot solve the problem? have you solved the error?

Answer (score 0):

That is a Lint check you can turn off in preferences. See the Configuring Lint section [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html).